# How to allow Flutter drawer to close when it has Dismissible inside it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an ending Drawer with a ListView of Dismissibles inside of it.

In each dismissible I have set 'direction: DismissDirection.endToStart'.

This correctly stops dissmising in the direction of the drawer close, but it doesn't close the drawer.

How do I allow the drawer to continue to close while still being able to dismiss to the other way?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve your problem by using `IgnorePointer` and `Listener` as parents for your `Dismissible`.

When the user opens the drawer,he'll find that all `Dismissibles` are disabled by default, but a single swipe in the opposite direction of drawer closing will activate them. Which is marked here by the color change from grey to black.

To close the `Drawer` again you have to deactivate `Dismissibles`, which is done by a single small swipe, then you can easily close with an `End to Start` swipe.

I know you wanted to achieve a similar behavior without lifting the finger off the screen, but I couldn't manage to do this because changing state requires the pointer event to complete.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Dismissibles demonstration';

  MyApp({Key key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: widget.appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: widget.appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState() ;
}

 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

   final items = List<String>.generate(100, (i) => "Item ${i + 1}");

   var ignoreSwitch = true ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Center(child: Text('Example')),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Listener(
          onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {
            print(event.delta.dx);
            if(event.delta.dx > 0.0){
              print('all items enabled');
              setState(() {
                      ignoreSwitch = false ;
                    });
            }
          },
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = items[index];
              if(index == 0){
                return DrawerHeader(child: Text('Drawer Header',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0),),decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan,),);
              }
              return Listener(
                onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent event) {
                  if(event.delta.dx > 0.0){
                    setState(() {
                      print('Inner listener working ! item $index enabled');
                      ignoreSwitch = false ;
                    });
                  }else{
                    setState(() {
                      print('Inner listener working ! item $index disabled');
                      ignoreSwitch = true ;
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: IgnorePointer(
                  ignoring: ignoreSwitch,
                  child: Dismissible(
                    key: Key(item),
                    direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                    background: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      // Remove the item from our data source.
                      setState(() {
                        items.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                    child: ListTileTheme(
                      textColor: ignoreSwitch ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
                      style: ListTileStyle.drawer,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('item $index', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        onTap: () {
                          //Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, ignore pointer and listener seem very handy.  I will work with them to see if I can get more close to the intended design.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Navigator.of(context).pop();

Comment: This works as a work around but prevents the drawers default smooth animation (for example being able to drag and only close it half way)